# Wrong values of float to int conversion when using big values?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am taking an input from a textbox from a user. That value is converted to a float using the following line:

```
float x = float.Parse(txt1.Text) * 8;
```

The float variable is then converted to an integer using the following line:

```
int switchOnDelayValue = (int)Math.Round(x);
```

Then I convert the integer into a hexadecimal equivalent string using:

```
valueToString = Convert.ToString(switchOnDelayValue, 16).PadLeft(8, '0');
```

The conversion from float to int works fine for mostly all values, except for some values near the maximum value of int. For example, when I input the value 268,435,455

```
float x = float.Parse(txt1.Text) * 8
```

**x** should now store **2,147,483,640**. However, the float stores the value as **2.14748365E+09**. And when the float is casted as an int, it overflows and gives a negative value.

Comment: A [float](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) has a precision of around 6-9 digits. You are experiencing the drawbacks of using a `float` when you want a more precise numeric type. You could consider a `double` which has a precision of ~15-17 digits and you *may* not run into the same issue.

Comment: It's a rounding error caused by the limitations of a 32-bit floating point number. A float can only hold up to 9 integer digits accurately. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types), `float` only has a precision of ~6-9 digits.

You're seeing a difference around the 9th digit. This is not unexpected. You probably need a `double`, which has a precision of ~15-17 digits, or a `decimal` which has a precision of 28-39 digits (but lower range).